# .htaccess DirectorySlash Off causes "/" to be inaccessible

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently using the following code in my .htaccess:
I have (A|B) because I have A.php, B.php, /A, and /B so I want the URL to redirect to A.php when /A is called.

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (A|B)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

However, with

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

I cannot access my root directory without a trailing slash. For e.g
If I have the files under directory /site, I can access /site/, /site/index, and /site/index.php but I cannot access using /site as it gives me a 403 error. I have seen on other SO questions that with DirectorySlash Off it will skip /site.

Is there a way to write a rule such that it applies to all files/directories apart from the root /site?
If not is there a way to remove trailing slashes for URLs where a .php file is involved?

I am asking this because when DirectorySlash is On, I may try /site/A?id=824 and the URL will become /site/A/?id=824.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you have autoindexes turned off, so if you try to access a directory without the trailing slash, it tries to list the contents of the directory and returns a 403 instead because it's not allowed to auto index.

Turning directory slash off means if someone goes to `/site` without the trailing slash, you get a list of contents of the `/site` directory, and not the index file (e.g. `/site/index.php`). This is why Directory Slash exists.

Instead of stripping off the slash, you'll have to check for the slash and remove it at the same time you're checking for the php file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1.php [L]
```

And don't turn off DirectorySlash.

Comment: It seems like something extremely weird was happening with DirectorySlash off since all my links are messed up now. I'll fix them up and tell you whether  the code you gave me works.

Comment: How should I be adding your code to my .htaccess? I added the code and I have a slash after my file, for e.g /A/?id=823. I don't want the '/'. Sorry I am new to this stuff.